# Destination Based Routing with Fortigate 60B Firewall

Tags: firewall, routing, fortinet

First let me start off that I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to networking so some terms what not may be over my head. I just know enough to get around.

So all traffic goes through the WAN 1 interface on the firewall. Is there a way to make certain traffic go through WAN 2 depending on what the destination is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes by using static routes. 
If you're beginner, this is easily done through the web interface by logging on to `https://your.router.ip/`

Using web interface go to Router > Static > Static Route > Create new.

Put destination in Destination IP/Mask field and select Device wan2, in Gateway field you're supposed to put IP address of the next hop router, which would probably be your ISP router (this is if you have static ip on your wan2 interface, if it's some DSL line with dynamic ip you can leave the zeros)

[image]

This makes all traffic that goes to the network you put in Destionation IP/Mask field go through wan2 interface

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Fortigate products, but generally speaking you would configure a static route for this and bind it to the second interface.